# Cover letter for supporting documents

Tags: letter, cover-letter

I have already sent an official leave request letter to a university official. However, I do have another supporting document (another old letter) that would be good if I could attach it along with the already sent letter. Please note that I have already mentioned it in the previous letter, but didn't say it is attached. Now I hope to send it separately along with a cover letter. I hope a cover letter is necessary here. I have written the body of the letter down here, but not sure whether it is the best way to write it. Should I include any other information or do I need to do any changes here?

Re: [Same heading in the previous letter]

> This is additional information to support my request on the letter
>   dated [Date of my previous letter]. Please kindly find the attached
>   document of the letter dated [Date of the old letter] received from
>   [organization].
>
> Thank you in advance.
>
> Sincerely Yours,
>
> ..............
>
> [My name]

Comment: Hi Needy! Welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Unfortunately questions asking "what to write" are off-topic here. It appears you are asking within an academic context. You could probably ask this over on [academia.se] but be sure to read up on their rules for questions before posting. Good luck!

Comment: Additionally, I am unsure how this is not a duplicate of your [previous question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/45931/33442). If it is a duplicate you should edit your other question rather than reposting as a new one.